# Std::chrono or boost::chrono support for CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, time, c++-chrono

Running on Linux (uname says:)

```
Linux 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jul 27 15:55:46 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My tests show that clock_gettime calls with a clock id of CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE are an order of magnitude faster than calls that use a clock id CLOCK_MONOTONIC.

Here's a sample output from a test run which called clock_gettime one million times in a tight loop and measured the lapsed time in milliseconds:

```
CLOCK_MONOTONIC lapse 795
CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE lapse 27
```

This pleases me and makes the profiler results look better, however I was hoping that I could use std::chrono or boost::chrono for portability and standard conformance without sacrificing this speed.  Unfortunately I haven't found any way to convince chrono (either one) to use CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE when it's available.  I tried chrono::steady_clock, but the results are comparable to the CLOCK_MONOTONIC values.

Is there a way to specify to chrono that you are willing to sacrifice precision for speed?

Comment: Which one of the `std::chrono::` clocks did you use?

Comment: @5gon12eder: I just edited the question to indicate I tried std::chrono::steady_clock

Comment: If you know the characteristics of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE`, you can easily build your own custom chrono-style clock around it.  You just need a few `typedef`s, and a `now()` function.

Comment: I have just checked out `chrono.cc` in the GNU implementation and it only deals with `CLOCK_REALTIME` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.  There isn't even a macro provided to select the coarse clocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Howard said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003413/c11-or-boost-support-for-clock-monotonic-coarse#comment40724317_26003413) it's simple make your own clock - a type conforming to the C++11 [Clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Clock) requirements - that uses `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE` when it's available and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` otherwise ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c44ad03bb31cd3df)):

```
class fast_monotonic_clock {
public:
    using duration = std::chrono::nanoseconds;
    using rep = duration::rep;
    using period = duration::period;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<fast_monotonic_clock>;

    static constexpr bool is_steady = true;

    static time_point now() noexcept;

    static duration get_resolution() noexcept;

private:
    static clockid_t clock_id();
    static clockid_t test_coarse_clock();
    static duration convert(const timespec&);
};

inline clockid_t fast_monotonic_clock::test_coarse_clock() {
    struct timespec t;
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE, &t) == 0) {
        return CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE;
    } else {
        return CLOCK_MONOTONIC;
    }
}

clockid_t fast_monotonic_clock::clock_id() {
    static clockid_t the_clock = test_coarse_clock();
    return the_clock;
}

inline auto fast_monotonic_clock::convert(const timespec& t) -> duration {
    return std::chrono::seconds(t.tv_sec) + std::chrono::nanoseconds(t.tv_nsec);
}

auto fast_monotonic_clock::now() noexcept -> time_point {
    struct timespec t;
    const auto result = clock_gettime(clock_id(), &t);
    assert(result == 0);
    return time_point{convert(t)};
}

auto fast_monotonic_clock::get_resolution() noexcept -> duration {
    struct timespec t;
    const auto result = clock_getres(clock_id(), &t);
    assert(result == 0);
    return convert(t);
}
```