# Consistent Timestamping in C++ with std::chrono

Tags: c++, clock, ntp, c++-chrono

I'm logging timestamps in my program with the following block of code:

```
// Taken at relevant time
m.timestamp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch();


// After work is done
std::size_t secs = std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::seconds> (timestamp).count();
std::size_t nanos = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds> (timestamp).count() % 1000000000;
std::time_t tp = (std::time_t) secs;

std::string mode;
char ts[] = "yyyymmdd HH:MM:SS";
char format[] = "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S";
strftime(ts, 80, format, std::localtime(&tp));

std::stringstream s;
s << ts << "." << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(9) << nanos 
  << " - " << message << std::endl;
return s.str();
```

I'm comparing these to timestamps recorded by an accurate remote source. When the difference in timestamps is graphed and ntp is not enabled, there is a linear looking drift through the day (700 microseconds every 30 seconds or so).

[image: graph1]

After correcting for a linear drift, I find that there's a non-linear component. It can drift in and out hundreds of microseconds over the course of hours.

[image: graph2]

The second graph looks similar to graphs taken with same methodology as above, but NTP enabled. The large vertical spikes are expected in the data, but the wiggle in the minimum is surprising.

Is there a way to get a more precise timestamp, but retain microsecond/nanosecond resolution? It's okay if the clock drifts from the actual time in a predictable way, but the timestamps would need to be internally consistent over long stretches of time.

Comment: This isn't really going to be a C++ question, as the std::chrono functions just get the time from your OS / hardware.  It seems more likely to be about your hardware.

Comment: Last time I looked the "High Resolution Timer" supported in C++ (particularly Microsofts) was "iffy"   This Q/A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003413/stdchrono-or-boostchrono-support-for-clock-monotonic-coarse might be of interest although I was trying to achieve a different goal

Answer (score 4):

`high_resolution_clock` has no guaranteed relationship with "current time".  Your system may or not alias `high_resolution_clock` to `system_clock`.  That means you may or may not get away with using `high_resolution_clock` in this manner.

Use `system_clock`.  Then tell us if the situation has changed (it may not).

Also, better style:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
auto timestamp = ... // however, as long as it is based on system_clock
auto secs = duration_cast <seconds> (timestamp);
timestamp -= secs;
auto nanos = duration_cast<nanoseconds> (timestamp);
std::time_t tp = system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::time_point{secs});
```

- Stay in the chrono type system as long as possible.
- Use the chrono type system to do the conversions and arithmetic for you.
- Use `system_clock::to_time_t` to convert to `time_t`.

But ultimately, none of the above is going to change any of your results.  `system_clock` is just going to talk to the OS (e.g. call `gettimeofday` or whatever).

If you can devise a more accurate way to tell time on your system, you can wrap that solution up in a "chrono-compatible clock" so that you can continue to make use of the type safety and conversion factors of chrono durations and time_points.

```
struct my_super_accurate_clock
{
    using rep        = long long;
    using period     = std::nano;  // or whatever?
    using duration   = std::chrono::duration<rep, period>;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<my_super_accurate_clock>;

    static const bool is_steady = false;

    static time_point now();  // do super accurate magic here
};
```

Comment: I think high_resolution_clock is aliased to system_clock for me (running CentOS Linux). Changing clock to system_clock produces timestamps with the same resolution. Will take some time to measure drift over a day.

Comment: Ok, gcc's implementation is known to alias `high_resolution_clock` to `system_clock`.  So correcting this won't change anything for you except to make your code more portable.

Comment: Thanks for the clean-up version. Yeah, I think VS does the same alias. But if I understand the doc correctly, the cast to time_t will be nonsense on a system which uses a steady_clock (which has no conversion to wall clock time). I'm surprised I get nanosecond resolution on system clock.

Comment: VS and libc++ alias `high_resoluiton_clock` to `steady_clock`.  And you are correct that `steady_clock` will have no relationship to wall clock time.  It is like a stopwatch (that doesn't stop).  Great for timing things.

Comment: Fwiw, here is another way to break `system_clock::time_point` into a date and hour:min:sec:nanosec:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html

Comment: Yes. I'm wondering if a custom clock based on steady_clock might work. I can extrapolate wall clock times based on two recordings of system_clock and steady_clock. Then, as long as steady_clock is actually steady, the results should be a linear transformation away from the accurate time source

Comment: I don't know if that will give you better accuracy or not.  It sounds like an interesting experiment and I'd love to hear how it comes out. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that unless your machine is very unusual, the underlying hardware simply isn't *capable* of providing a particularly reliable measurement of time (at least on the scales you are looking at).

Whether on your digital wristwatch or your workstation, most electronic clock signals are internally generated by a [crystal oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator). Such crystals have both long (years) and short-term (minutes) variation around their "ideal" frequency, with the largest short-term component being variation with temperature. Fancy lab equipment is going to have something like a [crystal oven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oven) which tries to keep the crystal at a constant temperature (above ambient) to minimize temperature related drift, but I've never seen anything like that on commodity computing hardware.

You see the effects of crystal inaccuracy in a different way in both of your graphs. The first graph simply shows that your crystal ticks at a somewhat large offset from true time, either due to variability at manufacturing (it was always that bad) or long-term drift (it got like that over time). Once you enable NTP, the "constant" or average offset from true is easily corrected, so you'll expect to *average* zero offset over some large period of time (indeed the line traced by the minimum dips above and below zero).

At this scale, however, you'll see the smaller short term variations in effect. NTP kicks in periodically and tries to "fix them", but the short term drift is always there and always changing direction (you can probably even check the effect of increasing or decreasing ambient temperature and see it in the graph).

You can't avoid the wiggle, but you could perhaps increase the NTP adjustment frequency to keep it more tightly coupled to real time. Your exact requirements aren't totally clear though. For example you mention:

> It's okay if the clock drifts from the actual time in a predictable
>   way, but the timestamps would need to be internally consistent over
>   long stretches of time.

What does "internally consistent" mean? If you are OK with arbitrary drift, just use your existing clock without NTP adjustments. If you want something like time that tracks real time "over large timeframes" (i.e,. it doesn't get *too* out of sync), why could use your internal clock in combination with periodic polling of your "external source", and change the adjustment factor in a smooth way so that you don't have "jumps" in the apparent time. This is basically reinventing NTP, but at least it would be fully under application control.